# onEdit(e) not generating trigger event when cell value changes due to inbuilt function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Below code monitors cell value changes in between  (Row 1 to Row 5, column 1 to column 5), and it tracks and log event in different sheet.
Which is working only when changes are being done manually in spreadsheet cells. (because onEdit(e) function only tracks the cell value changes edited manually not by any other functions)

If cell value changes due to some inbuilt mathematical functions (Example : B2 = C2+D2 where cell value of B2 will change automatically when C2 / D2 changes ) But with this code i can not see event getting triggered for value of B2 cell.

Can anybody help to find solution or workaround with below code.

Thanks

Code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "SheetA" &&
    e.range.columnStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 5 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 1 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5
      ) {
    //Logger.log("the cell is in range");
      var sheetsToWatch = ['SheetA'];
      var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";  
      var timestamp = new Date();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
      var sheetName = sheet.getName();

        // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
      if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

        // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
      var matchFound = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
      if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
       }
      if (!matchFound) return;


      var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
      var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

      var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
      if (!changelogSheet) {
      // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
      changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
      // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
      // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
      changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
       }
     changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
  }
```

Comment: This is functioning as designed. The edit trigger will not fire unless the change is directly by a user.

Comment: Is there any other way or option where we can get trigger for cell value change even the value is being changed by other function

Answer (score 2):

### There is a workaround:

1. Create two separate spreadsheets - spreadsheet number 1 contains your original data and formula, spreadsheet number 2 contains your script and an empty `SheetA`
2. Assign to cell `A1` in `SheetA` of `Spreadsheet2` a formula `=IMPORTRANGE(IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)`, whereby `spreadsheet_url` is the URL of `Spreadsheet 1` and `range_string` the range of interest (e.g. `"SheetA!A1:E"`)
3. Use [Scriptproperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store cell values
4. Find the modified cell by comparing old values against new values, each time there is a change in the sheet of interest
5. Modify your script as following:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheetsToWatch = ['SheetA'];

function initialSetUp(){//run this function only once, unless your range of interest changes
  for (var k = 0; k < sheetsToWatch.length; k++) { 
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sheetsToWatch[k]);
    var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,5,5); //change if required
    var values=range.getValues(); 
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('values '+sheet.getSheetName()+i+"-"+j,values[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function Edit() {
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var k = 0; k < sheetsToWatch.length; k++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[k])) 
      matchFound = true;
   }
  if (matchFound == true) {
    var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,5,5); //change if required
    var values=range.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
        var scriptValue=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('values '+sheetName+i+"-"+j);
        var newValue=sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1).getValue();
        Logger.log(scriptValue);
        Logger.log(newValue);
        if(newValue!=scriptValue){ 
          var cell=sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1);
          var timestamp = new Date(); 
          var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
          var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue(); 
          var changelogSheetName = "Changelog"; 
          var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName); 
          if (!changelogSheet) { 
            changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
            //Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
            changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
            changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
            } 
              changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]); 
              PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('values '+i+"-"+j,newValue);
          }
        }
      }
    }     
}
```

6. Add to the new function `Edit()` an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onChange`.

> EXPLANATION:

> - onEdit trigger cannot detect changes in values triggered by a formula
> - onChange cannot detect changes caused by cell formulas, but it can detect changes triggered by IMPORTRANGE

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka, thanks for your suggestion and workaround. When tried your suggestion and followed all above steps,  I see issue while generating a change log, it only updates the log for A1 cell in spreadsheet 2  where =IMPORTRANGE((spreadsheet_url, range_string) configured  in A1 cell for spreadsheet 2.

Comment: Hi Ziganotschka thanks for your reply, unfortunately that is also not working, randomly it gives A1 value in log or sometimes even not generating the log even after change, even if i try populate specific address of specific cells.

Comment: I came up with a solution using script properties, see my updated response.